"Mastery goals aims (yes, with -s) to learn or attain skill <...>" - A typo?
I was sure that in Present Simple in the third person singular, the verb always ends in -s: he wants, she needs, he gives, she thinks. While in the third person plular, -s is not used: they want.
But then why there is "aims" and not "aim" in the following example?

Mastery goals (aims to learn or attain skill) have traditionally been portrayed in achievement-motivation literature as the optimal goal for ensuring objective performance and well-being outcomes (relative to performance goals - aims to outperform others). (https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/37951843)

Maybe the word "aim" is special in some way?

It's being used as a noun here. It's in apposition to "goals". "Mastery goals, which are aims to learn or attain skill..."
Still, not very elegantly phrased. Perhaps the writer felt that repeating "goals" immediately was a style faux pas, but it would certainly have been clearer both for parsing the syntax and for identifying that the parenthesis is intended to recapitulate "mastery goals".
The use of "skill" as a mass noun (or the dropping of the article before it?) compounds the clunkiness.
